# How to define an organizational hierarchy in Visio 2010?

Tags: charts, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

How do you create the relationships between positions in a Visio 2010 Organizational Chart?

I have created the chart, added several positions to the chart, and now I wish to define which positions are sub-ordinate to other positions.

Currently I am trying to link them using the connector tool. Sometimes this works correctly, but other times Visio gets the relationship the wrong way round.

What is the correct way to define the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visio tells me "drop a subordinate shape on top of it's superior".  I tried it and it seems to work fine.